# In MaterialUI, how do I apply a class to my Typography element?

Tags: css, styles, material-ui, overflow, typography

In my material-ui component, I want to create an ellipsis when my Typography element overflows.  I created these styles ...

```
const styles = (theme) => ({
  root: {
    textAlign: "left",
    margin: theme.spacing(2),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    color: theme.color.secondary,
  },
  cardHeader: {
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(0),
  },
  cardContent: {
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  rowBody: {
    width: "100%",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    alignItems: "center",
    display: "flex",
  },
  halfRow: {
    width: "50%",
  },
  address: {
    "& .MuiTypography-h5": {
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      overflow: "hidden",
    },
  }
```

and I applied the "address" class to my Typography element like so

```
            <Typography variant="h5" className={classes.address}>
              <a href={`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"${location}"`}>{location}</a>
            </Typography>
```

However, the ellipsis is not appearing and the element is wrapping

[image]

What else do I need to do to apply a style to my Typography element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your address class should be added to the parent of the Typography component else the style chaining won't work.

```
address: {
    "& .MuiTypography-h5": {
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      overflow: "hidden",
    },
  }
```

What it means is that find a class .MuiTypography-h5 inside address class and apply the style but there isn't any.

Also I recommend you use makeStyles to create styles.

```
const styles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  address: {
    "& .MuiTypography-h5": {
      textOverflow: "ellipsis",
      overflow: "hidden"
    }
  }
}));
export default function App() {
  const classes = styles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.address}>
      <Typography variant="h5">
        126 Phillips Key Suite 042 West Kentucky
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yup, putting it at that parent element was the key.  Great job!